# Hibernate entity id TABLE generator style is creating inconsistent ID values

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to generate entities with incremental primary key. Used TABLE generator with following configuration.

```
@TableGenerator(name = "OTPSEQUENCE", table = "TB_OTP_SEQ_GEN", pkColumnName = "SEQUENCE_NAME", valueColumnName = "SEQUENCE_VALUE", pkColumnValue = "OTP_NO ", allocationSize = 2000, initialValue = 1)
```

**Single instance:**

High concurrency is required and thus assigned allocationSize to 2000.
Tested with single node deployment and the results were as expected .The primary key was increasing by factor "1" for every record.
Total no of records persisted were 1.5 million and the max value of ID was 1.502 million,which is as expected.

**Multiple instances:**

Now i have changed the deployment environment with load balancer having multiple instances of same service. Now the results were entirely different.
For same load the max value of ID went to billions. I am not able to contemplate what is happening here. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: did the number of records that were persisted was same in both the cases?

Comment: How are you doing the load balancing?

Comment: @Ankur, Total no of records are same in the both cases.

Comment: @Kayaman, Distributing the load equally between two instances.

Comment: Is this service of yours gets triggered by a scheduler? As in is it a cron job?

Comment: @Ankur,Used Jmeter to push the load with 10,000 threads parallely.